# Return array index from $elemMatch query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Say I have a document like this

```
{
  title : 'myTitle',
  favorites : [{name : 'text', number : 6}, {name : 'other', number : 4}]
}
```

I would like to return the array index (if any) from where the embedded document was retrieved within the favorites array.

Say I have the following query

```
 {title : 'myTitle'}
```

and the projection

```
 {favorites : {$elemMatch : {name : 'text', number : 6} }}
```

if the projection returns the document AND it contains a favorites array with the sub document, is there a way to know at which index that sub document was found? Which in this case is index 0.

The reason I would like the index is because as soon as I retrieve the document, I proceed to update it, and it would boost the performance if I had a specific index to update instead of using `$elemMatch` again which would cause mongo to iterate through all the array entries until finding the document that matches.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood you requirement, there is one risk i see with updating the array entries based on the index in case of multiple transactions. Say you have retrieved the array index you want to update in the document and subsequently another transaction deletes an array element from this document. In this case your index might point to a wrong element and it could result in updating array element in the document.

Comment: I understand, however no array entries will be duplicated and no entries will ever be deleted from the array.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible using the `$elemMatch` operator. If you are using `mongodb 3.2`, you could make use of the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator and `aggregate` instead of doing a `find()`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match:{"favorites.name":"text","favorites.number":6}},
{$unwind:{"path":"$favorites","includeArrayIndex":"index"}},
{$match:{"favorites.name":"text","favorites.number":6}}
])
```

The document would be returned, with its array index in the field - `index`. If you want the entire document, with other array elements, you would have to `$group`, after `$unwind` instead of `$match`.

For previous versions, iterating the array in the client side, and getting the sub document's index would be the way to go.